# Multiple conditions and __builtin_expect

Tags: c++, gcc

I have the below code in a utility library I use:

```
#ifndef NO_HINT_BRANCH_PREDICTION
#  ifndef  LIKELY
#   define LIKELY(expr)    __builtin_expect(!!(expr),1)
#  endif
#  ifndef  UNLIKELY
#   define UNLIKELY(expr)  __builtin_expect(!!(expr),0)
#  endif
#else
#  ifndef  LIKELY
#   define LIKELY(expr)    (expr)
#  endif
#  ifndef  UNLIKELY
#   define UNLIKELY(expr)  (expr)
#  endif
#endif
```

I am working on some of my own code that parses a TCP message and has to validate a lot of fields. If any of the fields are wrong I go into an error condition and close the connection. In other words each field has one of two cases:

- It is correct and just move on (by far the normal case)
- It is wrong and shut down the connection (an error, I don't care about performance here)

I am aware that documentation warns against using `__builtin_expect` saying "programmers are notoriously bad at predicting how their programs actually perform" but this seems like an obvious usage

As for the question, there are some cases where a field can be wrong in more than one way. Do these statements have the same intended meaning or is one preferable?

```
if (UNLIKELY(
    someField == nullValue ||
    someField == 0
))

if (
    UNLIKELY(someField == nullValue) ||
    UNLIKELY(someField == 0)
))
```

I am using: `gcc version 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2) (GCC)`

Comment: `__builtin_expect` is not part of the C++ standard and only exists by compiler extension. Please include which compiler you're using in your question (presumably GCC or Clang?)

Comment: @Brian, I added my GCC version

Comment: C++20 introduces `[[likely]]` and `[[unlikely]]` and they are used differently - you won't be able to choose there. As fro your question - it is unlikely to have any difference for simple expressions.

Comment: @StaceyGirl, I am using c++17

Comment: @asimes Yes, but my point is that C++20 doesn't let you choose anything here, so it is likely that this doesn't matter in most implementations.